# What rendering engine does Google's PageSpeed and mobile-friendly test use?

Tags: google, mobile, google-pagespeed

You'd think just "webkit", but the screenshots it shows me (and the issues it finds) are quite different to anything that I've seen via devtools device testing or using actual devices.

Is it maybe just an outdated version of webkit?

Without knowing what they're using it's hard to know how to fix the issues, and I feel they'll negatively affect my search index rankings if I don't.

Comment: Yes they [use webkit](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/faq),but I don't know what version they are using it correctly, so can't add anything. But what suggestion are you getting after testing your site?

Comment: I'm told that my design doesn't fit in the viewport (i.e. results in horizontal scrolling).  And in the screenshot they show I can see that that is a problem.  I can't replicate it in any browser/device that I try though!

Comment: Then set your main container width is 320px for mobile devices or use percentage or vh units or set width:100%  . Google chrome dev tool, and other online site will give you same error. your problem is you have not set perfect size for your viewport.

Comment: I've already told you that google chrome devtools does NOT show me the same problem...

Comment: You may not tested all of the devices, click on edit option on mobile icon, and you will see many old devices like nokia and blackbarry, so test your site on that. Most of our smartphones now come with more than 360w, so either you should test your site on 320w devices or create that kind of devices on chrome dev tools.

Comment: Already done I'm afraid, thanks though.

Comment: According to [What rendering engine does google's pagespeed and mobile-friendly test use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163872/what-rendering-engine-does-googles-pagespeed-and-mobile-friendly-test-use) it uses "a stripped down version of Chrome for Android"

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was cross posted to StackOverflow.